# Groupby Count Query On Two Tables Filtered by Condition on Third Table

Tags: sql

I have three tables: Category, Mail and Classification. The relationship between the tables is outlined in this SQLFiddle with some sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/118b24/3/0

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Mail` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Classification` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mail_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (mail_id) REFERENCES Mail(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I first run a query to get the count of emails assigned to each category:

```
SELECT Category.name, count(Classification.category_id) FROM Category LEFT OUTER JOIN Classification ON Classification.category_id = Category.id GROUP BY Category.name
```

Which works fine.

But I would now like to add a filter based on the date that is in the Email collection. If I had a join with a filter collection:

```
SELECT Category.name, count(Classification.category_id) FROM Category JOIN Mail ON Mail.date < '2019-03-24' LEFT OUTER JOIN Classification ON Classification.category_id = Category.id GROUP BY Category.name
```

But now the count only doubles and it seems the filter isn't even applied. Why isn't the filter working and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag are all helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `JOIN` condition between `Classification` and `Mail`:

```
SELECT ca.name, count(cl.category_id)
FROM Category LEFT JOIN
     Classification cl
     ON cl.category_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
     Mail m
     ON m.id = cl.mail_id AND  -- your JOIN key goes here
        m.date < '2019-03-24'
GROUP BY c.name ;
```